# Why does minSdkVersion 27 -> 28 double APK size?

Tags: android, apk, android-sdk-tools

I recently updated `minSdkVersion` to 28, compiled a signed release build and noticed that file size increased from 9.2 to 20.3 MB. Changed it back to 27 (only thing changed), cleaned a created a second signed release build. Then used **Analyze APK** in Android Studio to compare the two:

[Analyze APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imGDI.png)

The Raw file size of classes.dex and classes2.dex jumped from 3.4/3.3 MB to 9.3/8.2 MB with the same number of referenced methods. Is there anyone that knows why?

A few notes: The `targetSdkVersion` is 31. The app is not distributed via Google Play. Shrinking (minifyEnabled) is false and should not be turned on for various reasons. I am more interested in what is actually causing this than suggestions on how to decrease the file size.

I also compiled with minSdkVersion 29, 30, 31, 32, and 33 without seeing any big differences between 28 and up.

Comment: After changing `minSdkVersion` have you performed a `clean` on your project to delete all caches?

Comment: yes, I always perform clean before building signed release builds

Comment: Then this is indeed strange. I would recommend instead of using Analyze APK in AS try to decompile your app versions using [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and see if you can see differences in the number of smali files and their size.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the DEX is uncompressed (Play Store relies on [App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) for size optimization) by default unless the flag [useLegacyPackaging](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/DexPackagingOptions#useLegacyPackaging:kotlin.Boolean) is used:

> Whether to use the legacy convention of compressing all dex files in
> the APK. If null, dex files will be uncompressed when minSdk >= 28.
>
> This property does not affect dex file compression in APKs produced
> from app bundles.

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.gradle` file, setting the `useLegacyPackaging` to `true` under `dex` will solve the issue

```
android {

    packagingOptions {

        dex {
            useLegacyPackaging true
        }
    }
}
```